# REST API doesn't allow GET Requests from localhost (axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, axios

I've been trying to get a response from a REST API through Axios, I've tried setting the headers up, specifically the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as stated in the error message, which seems to be the main problem, because even as I insert the required header, it still doesn't acknowledge the header.

```
axios
   .get(url, {
     headers: {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
       crossDomain: true,
       "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
     },
     params: {
       access_key: API_KEY,
       adults: adults,
       origin: origin,
       destination: destination,
       departure: departure,
     },
   })
   .then((res) => {
     console.log(res.data);
   });
```

Comment: You have to configure CORS backend-side. There is a workaround, launch your browser without CORS check (depends on the browser and the operating system), for development purposes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be set on the backend, not the frontend. For example, in PHP, you would set the header at the beginning of the file:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

And then in your frontend, however you'd usually do, send the data. **This solution is only for those with access to the backend of the server you're querying.**

Comment: Thanks for the response! But how can I make it possible to send a get request from React using Axios to a REST API?

Comment: @ANDEUS I'm assuming that your need for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` signifies that the API is not accepting requests from any origin, meaning that you will not be able to send a `GET` request unless you have access to the backend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

CORS is configured on the backend, here's an example with a NodeJS backend and a ReactJS frontend.

```js
//API
import express from "express";
const app = express();
import cors from "cors";

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3000",
    ],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

//React Frontend with useEffect and useState
useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const results = await axios.get("/users/table", config);
      setRows(results.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [setRows, state, token]);
```